# How can i fix Mapbox - ANR - Broadcast of Intent?

Tags: java, android, mapbox-android

I am using Mapbox navigation in my app, something like Uber, I start a trip and  start navigation to some point. Everything is working fine except at some point of the navigation my app freezes and i get a warning that my App isn`t responding.

Here`s my dependency

`implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.40.0'`
 
And my Class that recieves the LocationEngineResult:

```
public class LocationCallback implements LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {

private final WeakReference<NavigationFragment> activityWeakReference;
private Location prelocation;

public LocationCallback(NavigationFragment navigationFragment) {
    this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<NavigationFragment>(navigationFragment);
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
    Log.e("Tag", "NavigationFragment locationEngineResult");
    NavigationFragment context = activityWeakReference.get();
    if (context != null) {
        Location location = result.getLastLocation();
        Log.d("Tag", "Result location: " + location.toString());
        if (location == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(prelocation == null){
            context.checkFirstUpdate(location);
            context.onLocationChanged(location);
            prelocation = location;
        }
        else{
            if(AppHelper.distance(prelocation.getLatitude(), prelocation.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()) > 0){
                context.checkFirstUpdate(location);
                context.onLocationChanged(location);
                prelocation = location;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    Log.d("Tag", "On failure exception" + exception.getMessage());
    Timber.e(exception);
}
}
```

I am dealing with this for a few days and i asume my LocationEngine callback stops getting the result of my location.
Here is my Logcat:

  `PID: 18359
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.mapbox.android.telemetry.location.locationupdatespendingintent.action.LOCATION_UPDATED flg=0x10 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }
    Load: 2.85 / 4.21 / 4.5
    CPU usage from 901ms to -4460ms ago (2019-06-14 17:13:07.541 to 2019-06-14 17:13:12.902):
      24% 3658/system_server: 13% user + 10% kernel / faults: 7699 minor 6681 major`

Pleas, any suggestion may help. I can provide more code. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In my case the bug had somethimg to do with crashlitcs, after days of debugging and going to previous commits i ended up removing crashlitics but never could understand the problem.
Also the project didn't continue for long so i really can}t be sure if that completley solved the issue. Sory

Comment: Hi Marcos, I've the same problem. Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Hi Marcos, I've the same problem. Did you find any solution for it ?

Comment: Hi @Marcos, I've the same problem. Did you find any solution for it ?

Comment: Hi guys, i´ve updated my question, it`s not much but i hope it helps someone

Comment: There is an open issue in mapbox' repo: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/issues/126